# Composition series and Artin rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

As we know, if $A$ is Artin $R-$algebra and $M$ is finite generated,then $\operatorname{End}_A M$ is also an Artin $R-$algebra. My questions are:

> 1. If $A$ is an Artin ring and $M$ is finite generated, is $\operatorname{End}_A M$ an Artin ring?
> 2. If $A$ is an arbitrary ring and $M$ is a module with composition series, is $\operatorname{End}_A M$ an Artin ring?

Comment: by "Artin ring" do you mean that it is left and right Artinian?

Comment: @rschwieb as the answer below,if R is not left and right Artin,it has a counerexample.

Comment: I'm just asking because I do not know for sure what you mean by "Artin ring." An Artin $R$-algebra has a very specific meaning as a finitely generated algebra over a commutative artinian ring $R$. When you say "Artin ring" for $A$, I'm not positive what was intended.

Comment: If $A$ is right artinian and $M$ is a right $A$ module, then the first question could be simplified to say "$M$ has a composition series" since a finitely generated right $A$ module over a right Artinian ring $A$ necessarily has a composition series.

Comment: Maybe you already know, but it's known that the endomorphism ring of any module with a composition series is semiprimary (that is, $A/J(A)$ is Artinian, and $J(A)$ is a nilpotent ideal.)

Comment: @rschwieb  I don't know this,can you give a short proof?please,why Jacobson radical of endmorphism ring is nilpotent?thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407901/29335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2) the answer is no.  For example there exist rings $A$ such that $A$ is left Artinian but not right Artinian.  Left Artinian rings are left Noetherian so $A$, considered as a left $A$-module, has a composition series.  But the endomorphism ring of this module is the opposite ring $A^\text{op}$ which is not left Artinian.

Comment: if we consider R is commutative Artin ring,is there a counterexample?

Comment: +1 because I like the observation: I don't intend this comment to detract from it @Sky If you insist that $A$ is an Artin $R$-algebra, then the above strategy can't be employed since an Artin $R$ algebra is finitely generated over $R$, it must be left and right Artinian. But I'm not sure if you have realized that would happen or not...

Comment: @rschwieb I know this property,I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: @Sky I'm saying there is no *Artin $R$-algebra* that is one-sided Artinian.

Comment: @rschwieb yeah,I know this since the underlying ring is commutative Artin ring.